# Does using `await` always involve a microtask?

Tags: javascript, promise

Is the following code:

```
async function foo() {
  await 1
}
```

...equivalent to:

```
function foo() {
  return Promise.resolve(1).then(() => undefined)
}
```

Comment: Surely you've read the spec of `then` and `await` by now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.**

To both of your questions.